# The script "npm run migration:generate print error"

Tags: migration, nestjs, database-migration

When I try to migrate the nestjs project the console print an error. I am using a docker container and SQLPro Studio to establish a connection with the database. In the **package.json** file the scripts I create three new scripts for migrations:

```
"migration:generate": "ts-node node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:generate --config ./orm.config.json --name",

"migration:run": "ts-node node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:run --config ./orm.config.json",
    
"migration:revert": "ts-node node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:revert --config ./orm.config.json"
```

When running the command migration:generate the console print the next error:

```
PS C:\Users\DariXDani\pet-store> npm run migration:generate core

> pet-store@0.0.1 migration:generate C:\Users\DariXDani\pet-store
> ts-node node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:generate --config ./orm.config.json --name "core"

C:\Users\DariXDani\pet-store\node_modules\.bin\typeorm:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at main (C:\Users\DariXDani\pet-store\node_modules\ts-node\src\bin.ts:331:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DariXDani\pet-store\node_modules\ts-node\src\bin.ts:482:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pet-store@0.0.1 migration:generate: `ts-node node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:generate --config ./orm.config.json --name "core"`    
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pet-store@0.0.1 migration:generate script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\DariXDani\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-14T01_07_27_385Z-debug.log
```

I have run these commands `npm cache clean --force` and `npm install` but still does not work. Any help is welcome.

Comment: see this thread https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/706

Comment: yeah. I'd say: use another shell

Comment: I dig into it and in the end I solved the problem thanks to your link in short time I will be posting how I fix it.